# Check if a string features in a list entry in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

I have the below list:

```
my_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear']
```

I also have a data feed providing strings into my Python code. What I am looking to achieve is to compare the string to any entries within the list, and if there is a match, return a value. The strings being provided in the data feed may just be a partial match, and so, for example, there may be the strings `'anana'` or `'appl'`, for example. I want the script to also check for these partial strings to see if they exist in the list (e.g. if `'anana'` is a string passed, it is compared to my_list and matches as `True`).

My code so far is:

```
my_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear']
for entry in my_list:   
    if entry in my_string: #my_string being the passed variable string
        print "There is a match"
```

As said, the key to this is as that partial matches return true also and not just exact matches, so I want the above code to return true if `my_string = 'banan`, for example.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you probably want `if my_string in entry:` instead

Comment: Should be `if my_string in entry`

Comment: may be `if my_string in my_list` is what you are looking for

Comment: If you just want a shorter version of what you've got, you could use `if any(my_string in entry for entry in my_list)` .

Comment: [Solution 1] Finite State Transducers (As given in the answers below)
    [Solution 2] Suffix Array/Tree, Trie, Ternary Search Tree
    [Solution 3] NGrams

Answer (score 3):

```
my_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear']
for entry in my_list:   
    if my_string in entry: #my_string being the passed variable string
        print "There is a match"
```

The code that you wrote will check for partial strings of list variable in the given search string. But you want to do the opposite of it. So `my_string in entry` will work in the way you want it to.

Comment: If you only would like to know that there is a match, you should insert a break statement or write it in a function and use a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will give you a list of results of your partial or full matches:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(entry)
matches = [e for e in my_list if re.match(regex, e)]
if len(matches) > 0:
    print "There is are matches:", matches
```

Comment: match only works if the pattern is at the beginning of the string, no? i.e. 'ana' wont match in banana but 'ban' will

Answer (score 0):

I come from perl so i solve everything with regex:

```
import re
my_string = 'anana'
my_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear']


if [1 for item in my_list if re.search(my_string, item)]:
    print "There is a match"
```

search returns `None` if it didn't find anything

Comment: You have two clear disadvantages here: best-case performance is much worse, and using sum and list comprehensions decreases readability.

Comment: @Pinna_be ohh yea, Bhargavis solution is much better and i dont know why i even added the sum there, it is unnecessary